# Android UART Data

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to read data in Android from the device which is pushing data on UART BLE. I have searched many resources but still cannot be able to get the data.

I am able to see all the device services but I don't know how to read data from the UART. I have 5 services which are:

- 00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb

  - 00002a00-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb (characteristic)
  - 00002a01-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb (characteristic)
- 0000180a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb

  - 00002a29-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb (characteristic)
  - 00002a24-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb (characteristic)
  - 00002a25-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb (characteristic)
  - 00002a27-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb (characteristic)
  - 00002a26-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb (characteristic)
  - 00002a28-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb (characteristic)
  - 00002a23-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb (characteristic)
  - 00002a2a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb (characteristic)
- 49535343-5d82-6099-9348-7aac4d5fbc51

  - 49535343-026e-3a9b-954c-97daef17e26e (characteristic)
- 49535343-c9d0-cc83-a44a-6fe238d06d33

  - 49535343-aca3-481c-91ec-d85e28a60318 (characteristic)
- 49535343-fe7d-4ae5-8fa9-9fafd205e455

  - 49535343-1e4d-4bd9-ba61-23c647249616 (characteristic)
  - 49535343-8841-43f4-a8d4-ecbe34729bb3 (characteristic)
  - 49535343-4c8a-39b3-2f49-511cff073b7e (characteristic)

Comment: I'm really curious what device you are trying to connect to here. It isn't a Sole F85 by any change? If it is, did you get anywhere? I'm trying to understand the BLE services of that specific device myself and found your post.

Comment: Ah! I just realised that this a generic IoT BLE board that is put inside my treadmill. The board is called ISSC BM70.

Comment: Hi, this is my cross trainer, by the look of it. Did you identify the "49" services and characteristics ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `49535343-1e4d-4bd9-ba61-23c647249616` characteristic of the `49535343-fe7d-4ae5-8fa9-9fafd205e455` service should have write and notify (and maybe indicate) properties.

If you write to it from the client (phone), the data should come out of the UART at the server end, and if the server changes the property at its end you should get a notification at the phone of the new value.

This is what I'm seeing with a Microchip RN4870 module and the Microchip iOs app.